# Remove carriage return on last line in BCP SQL Server or Windows

Tags: sql, sql-server, vbscript, bcp

I have file with

```
    1,ABC
    2,DEF
    3,XYZ *+<CR>*
```

which is bcp'd out from the sql server.

I need the file to be like

```
    1,ABC
    2,DEF
    3,XYZ *-<NO -----CR>*
```

Dont want the Carriage return for the last line. Is there a way I can do this in SQL Server BCP or in dos batch or vb script

Answer (score 0):

You can .ReadAll the source file, remove the trailing vbCrLf (Trim won't work because it's restricted to spaces, just Left( sAll, Len( sAll ) - 1 ) may be enough, else use a RegExp.Pattern "\s*$"), and .Write (Not! .WriteLine) it back.